libreoffice xlsx to pdf get Unspecified Application Error
I use
soffice --convert-to 'pdf:calc_pdf_Export:{"SinglePageSheets":{"type":"boolean","value":"true"}}'  a.xlsx

to convert xlsx to pdf, but I got error like this
convert /tmp/a.ods as a Calc document -> /tmp/a.pdf using filter : calc_pdf_Export:{"SinglePageSheets":{"type":"boolean","value":"true"}}
/usr/include/c++/13.2.1/bits/unique_ptr.h:453: typename std::add_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::type std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator*() const [with _Tp = ScPrintState; _Dp = std::default_delete<ScPrintState>; typename std::add_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::type = ScPrintState&]: Assertion 'get() != pointer()' failed.
Unspecified Application Error

xlsx to pdf is correct while without SinglePageSheets, please help how can I use SinglePageSheets?
version: LibreOffice 7.6.7.2 60(Build:2)
os: alpine v3.19 in docker
I have install the jre, but still get error.
If I don't use {"SinglePageSheets":{"type":"boolean","value":"true"}}, xlsx to pdf work correct.

This seems more like a support question, which you could ask on the libreoffice mailing list.

SinglePageSheets seem allow in cmd:
https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/pdf_params.html?&DbPAR=SHARED&System=MAC#user%20interface
